# can i use only the eclipse IDE without using the myeclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, myeclipse

In my new project i work on, we use the myeclipse on top of Eclipse IDE.

Our architecture includes jsp, jsf, ajax, spring framework with hibernate persistence and also has blaze for some business validations. We also expose Web services. For the build we have the maven and ant. The server used is weblogic.Also like to mention that we use the Rational ClearCase for code versioning.

I know that myeclipse is bundled with loads of plugins to support the jsf, spring, hiberate, ant etc.

I really like to know whether the dependability of myeclipse plugins can be removed all together and customize the eclipse IDE to support the above architecture?

Kindly let me know your answers/ thoughts/ advices. Any piece of information will be highly valuable for me proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand why some people prefer MyEclipse, standard Eclipse distributions already have either equal or better tools. Personal preference, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The Latest MyEclipse 8.0 has a specific plugins manager from which you can selectively install/uninstall the features you need.

To uninstall or reinstall a Lite module, simply bring up the MyEclipse Dashboard using Help > Manage MyEclipse Plug-ins... (or MyEclipse > Manage MyEclipse Plug-ins)

[image]
<sub>(source: [myeclipseide.com](http://myeclipseide.com/modules/ContentExpress/img_repository/docs/80/lite-dashboard.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about removing plug-ins from Eclipse, because I use IntelliJ.  But I'd say that all the things you want to support are possible without plug-ins.  It's just a matter of how much work you want to do and how much assistance you feel you need.  You can always do whatever you want by hand.

If I go to Eclipse.org, I see that I can still download enterprise Java EE without MyEclipse.  Maybe that's a place to start.

What's the problem?  Is Eclipse too much of a memory hog with all those plug-ins?

I'm not sure what you'll replace all those plug-ins with if you remove them.  I'd also like to hear how you'll benefit if you do so.

I love IntelliJ, and I especially love giving Eclipse a hard time, but the fact is that all IDEs gobble up a lot of RAM these days.

Comment: IntelliJ is definitely a nice IDE (I use regularly Eclipse **and** Idea **and** NetBeans depending on what I'm doing, and where) and it was indeed superior to Eclipse some years ago: fast (actually, a state of the art Swing application), very intuitive, with extremely good refactoring support, etc. But honestly, I don't find that this is still true: IntelliJ became slower with time and Eclipse improved a lot in areas where Idea was stronger. In fact, Eclipse is currently my favorite IDE again.

Comment: The new indexing in IntelliJ 9 does take a while, but I'm not going back.

Answer (score 0):

I think your needs might be solved using Eclipse (at least most of them): the WTP (Web Tools Platform) contains plug-ins needed for jsp,... for spring see [this link in DZone](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/springide-using-spring-eclipse). Webservices, Maven and Ant are also supported.

I don't know exactly the situation about Weblogic and Clearcase, but I'd be surprised if they are not supported at least basically.